# Match exact number in a given string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use regexr.com to write an expression to match some specific numbers in the filenames below. The expression will then be used in a PHP preg_match() method to identify files that should be on the server; unmatched files will be deleted.

In this example, I want the expression to match 187906 and 187909 (so the other files can be deleted). I figured I could write (187906|187909) which works, but of course that would also match 11879066 or 11879099 and so on. Before and after the number will always be a non-numeric character; either alphabetic or a full-stop.

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root   2190476 Jan 26 16:48 source187905.jpg
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root   1691755 Jan 26 16:48 source187906.jpg
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root   1780389 Jan 26 16:48 source187907.jpg
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root   1692330 Jan 26 16:48 source187908.jpg
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root   1622615 Jan 26 16:48 source187909.jpg
```

Comment: \D is a non-numeric character so `\D(187906|187909)\D` I think would do it. or you could use a character class for alpha or full-stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)`:

```
/(?<!\d)(?:187906|187909)(?!\d)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UByqpx/1).

The `(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind will fail the match if there is a digit before either of the two numbers and `(?!\d)` negative lookahead will fail the match if there is a digit after either of the two numbers.

Since that number looks to be at the end of the file name with a specific extension, you may  even use

```
/(?<!\d)(?:187906|187909)\.jpg$/i
```

where `\.jpg$` will match `.jpg` at the end of the string (`$`) and `/i` modifier will make the pattern case insensitive.

Comment: This works for me and thank you for explaining your answer. :-)